# Can a VSCode extension trigger a function when a user hovers over a diagnostic?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Diagnostics show more information when hovering over them. I would like to trigger a function whenever the user hovers and stops hovering over the diagnostic area. Is this currently possible with an extension?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new context key coming in v1.46 presumably, see [editor hover context key](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/eff2fb75151dac67b6835584b6e91808ec1379ae).

```
editorHoverVisible
```

which is perhaps of some help.  I don't know how to detect precisely where that hover occurred though.